# Creating random numbers that add to 1 in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to generate a list of random numbers that must all add to 1 (or 100 if that's easier) but can't figure out how to do it. I know Netlogo allows you to create random numbers but can't find a way to set the rule that the addition of the generated numbers must be 1. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
let xs n-values 5 [ -> random-float 1 ]
let total sum xs
set xs map [ x -> x / total ] xs
```